# How to get browser-sync to watch files and auto-navigate to changed / added file

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, livereload, build-system

I'm working on many .html files and would like to have browser-sync auto-navigate to the changed file.

1. Browser-Sync started, browser showing `http://localhost/file-01.html`
2. Edit `file-42.html`, hit save
3. Browser-Sync navigates to `http://localhost/file-42.html`

Normally if I save `file-42.html` `file-01.html` reloads in the browser, which is not useful. I want to keep the editor and browser in sync on save.

What could I use to get this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I used to be able to do it in [gulp-server-livereload](https://github.com/hiddentao/gulp-server-livereload) but that's no longer maintained and buggy now, so I have to move to another local dev server. [Feature request: Option to auto-navigate to changed file · Issue #46 · hiddentao/gulp-server-livereload](https://github.com/hiddentao/gulp-server-livereload/issues/46)

[live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/) doesn't have this feature either [Feature request: Option to auto-navigate to changed file · Issue #304 · tapio/live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/304)

In **browser-sync** I was able to get it working by abusing [`.notify(msg, timeout)`](https://browsersync.io/docs/api#api-notify)

```
// gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const bs = require('browser-sync').create();

function autoNavigate (cb) {
  bs.init({
    // Don't reload *.html, auto-navigate to changed instead
    ignore: ['*.html', 'gulpfile.js']
    notify: true
  });

  bs.watch('*.html', (event, file) => {
    if (event === 'change') {
      bs.notify(`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/${file}" />`);
    }
    if (event === 'add') {
      bs.notify(`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/${file}" />`);
    }
    // Needs debouncing or else rename events 404
    if (event === 'unlink') {
      // File removed, navigate to index
      bs.notify('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/" />');
    }
  });

  cb();
}

exports.serve = autoNavigate;
```

This is a hacky solution, though it does have the upside that it's server-side only. Any page can be auto-navigated, without having any client-side code in it to receive and interpret messages from the server.

Is there a proper way to get this behavior? `bs.reload('file-42.html`)` doesn't work. I've looked at the API, maybe something I've missed?